# How to Install XP and Ubuntu dual boot on a RAID 0 and RAID 1 respective setup?

Tags: windows-xp, raid, grub, multi-boot, ubuntu-12.04

I know that installing XP and Ubuntu in a 'normal' (non-RAID) environment is easiest when installing XP first as the MBR isn't overwritten by XP if XP is installed after. But if I have a RAID 1 setup for Ubuntu and a RAID 0 setup for XP, then what order should I go about doing this and as it's a RAID setup, where should I install grub? As I understand it, the boot partition should be outside the RAID? I came across this article (http://stinebaugh.info/installing-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts-using-hardware-raid1/) however which shows a way of installing grub without doing this. Am I safe to install Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're planning on having two logical drives and 4 physical drives? IE: I have two drives mirroring one another that I've installed ubuntu onto, while I have an XP install on two drives that are striped for raid 0 (no mirror just two physical drives acting as one for performance)

I'd just install Ubuntu to your mirrored drives with grub then install xp to the other raid config and set the ubuntu drive as your boot drive, grub should detect the xp install if not just manually add it.

Comment: I have 2x1TB physical drives. 900GB RAID 1, and what's left is RAID 0. I am not concerned about the data on the XP side which will be on RAID 0. Ubuntu installation has just failed whilst trying to install grub to /dev/sda. Wouldn't installing XP afterwards wipe out the MBR like it usually does when installing XP after?

Comment: That sounds like a software raid config, most hardware raids I've had in the past do full disc raid, not by partition which it sounds like you are.

The last dual boot install i did installed the mbr to the disc the os was installed on, so grub should still be intact, but honestly to be on the safe side it's probably best to install xp, then ubuntu since that's really the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Well, it could possibly be fake RAID, I configured it in the BIOS, and it allowed me to do partial disc raid. As this is one disc, so installing the OS would overwrite the MBR, so would require XP to be installed first (easiest option). I am wondering whether I should just use a mdadm in ubuntu to setup RAID, looks like it might be the easiest option.